# Can not querying from CoreData in swift 3

Tags: xcode, core-data, swift3

I'm using this class function to search for a record by one field. The problem here is this always returns nil, and if remove the predicate will return any row from the database. I'm using Xcode v 8.0

```
class func visitorWithCode(code: String, inManagedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Visitor? {
    print(code)

    var visitor: Visitor? = nil
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Visitor> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Visitor")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "barcodeNo == \(code)")
    fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1
    let fetchedData = try! context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    if (!fetchedData.isEmpty) {
        print(fetchedData.first)
        visitor = fetchedData.first! as Visitor

        return visitor
    }
    else {
        return visitor
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `NSPredicate(format: "barcodeNo == %@", code)` instead.

Comment: already tried, same result.

Comment: How is the "barcodeNo" property defined? What does `print(fetchRequest.predicate)` show?

Comment: Have you also tried using `NSPredicate(format: "barcodeNo == %@", argumentsArray: [code])`? Had to convert my predicates to that format to make them work with Swift 3.0. If I didn't use the `argumentsArray` and do what @MartinR suggested it didn't work.

Comment: Turned out the values for barcodeNo did not store properly. I checked other fields and it worked then I solved the problem from the source.